# Cannot open folders located on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed, using its default file manager Nautlius. Double-clicking any folder located on the desktop does not open the folder. The following folders are affected:

- Trash
- Home
- Any folder located on the desktop

Right-click > Open does not work either.

Comment: Are you able to access the folders in Nautilus?

Comment: Make sure Ubuntu is fully updated and has the proper graphics drivers, if applicable (i.e. Nvidia).

Comment: @danzel Yes, I can access the folders when opening them directly in Nautilus.

Comment: @MichaelBay That's the case. The system is up-to-date with all its drivers.

Answer (score 11):

This post has been around for a long time. I met the same problem today, and I googled it. So I share my solutions I found.

1. Open a terminal, type in **ps -A | grep nautilus** to know the respect **pid** for **nautilus**.
2. Type in **sudo kill -9 pid**. Then the folder can be opened.

Comment: Yes its killed, And?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem and quickly wanted to share my amateurish "solution" here.

*The issue: nautilus would not open any folder located on desktop by doubleclicking or by right-click and "open". (Browsing through the filemanager and opening the desktop folders from there worked fine - just as everything else concerned nautilus).*

What I did:

For the sake of completeness I want to mention that I started with a lot of uninstalling, purging, reinstalling, apt-getting etc. of nautilus. Being rather a beginner than an expert I can't assess properly whether this step was necessary at all, but if you want to do it:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus  

sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

As mentioned, this didn't change a thing, but here comes my breakthrough attempt: I reinstalled the gnome-shell:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

(I somewhat suspected / guessed that something else apart from nautilus messed with my desktop folders and kept it from acting in a well-behaved manner).

That's it. Maybe this works for you or at least gives you a hint to check your system for stuff that interacts with your desktop and isn't set up neatly.

Comment: It works!! Please bold/highlight the respective command section

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Playing with Gnome Tweaks app, turning on/off system folders on desktop, sometimes fixes the issue, randomly, but it returns back again, especially when logging out.
Running dome diagnostics, all I can tell is that if you keep nautilus running prior running nautilus-desktop, it will fix the problem, but you have to keep nautilus running, which is silly. Otherwise, running nautilus-desktop first, yields the following error:

> Unable to create File Manager freedesktop proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.FileManager1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.FileManager1: No such file or directory